# javascript class calling XMLHttpRequest internally, then handling onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, class, properties, xmlhttprequest, onreadystatechange

this thing almost works:

```
function myClass(url) {

this.source = url;
this.rq = null;
this.someOtherProperty = "hello";

// open connection to the ajax server
this.start = function() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        this.rq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (this.rq.overrideMimeType)
        this.rq.overrideMimeType("text/xml"); 
    } else
        this.rq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    try {
        this.rq.onreadystatechange = connectionEvent;
        this.rq.open("GET", this.source, true);
        this.rq.send(null);
        this.state = 1;
    } catch (err) {
        // some error handler here
    }

}

function connectionEvent() {
    alert("i'm here");
    alert("this doesnt work: " + this.someOtherProperty);
}
```

} // myClass

so it's nothing more than having the XMLHttpRequest object as a member of my class, instead of globally defined, and invoking it in the traditional way. however, inside my connectionEvent callback function, the meaning of "this" is lost, even though the function itself is scoped inside myClass. i also made sure that the object that i instantiate from myClass is kept alive long enough (declared global in the script).

in all the examples of using javascript classes that i saw, "this" was still available inside the inner functions. for me, it is not, even if i take my function outside and make it a myClass.prototype.connectionEvent. what am i doing wrong? thank you.

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow :) Rather use 4 spaces instead of a tab for each indentation. Then, when you copypaste code here, you've to indent the *complete* piece with another 4 spaces. You can do it by selecting the piece and then pressing `010101` button in message editor toolbar or `Ctrl+K` key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that in Javascript, `this` is defined entirely by how a function is *called*, not where it's defined. This is different than some other languages.

To have `this` mean what you expect, you'd have to ensure that explicitly by "binding" it:

```
this.start = function() {
    var self = this; // Set up something that survives into the closure

    /* ...lots of stuff omitted... */

    this.rq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // Call `connectionEvent`, setting `self` as `this` within the call
        connnectionEvent.call(self);
    };
```

There's more information about `this` management in [this blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html), but basically: When a function is called without any particular effort made to set `this`, `this` within the function will always be the global object (`window`, on browsers). There are two ways to set `this` when making a call:

1. Using `Function#call` (or `Function#apply`) as I did above, passing in the object reference to use as `this` as the first parameter. That calls the function and sets `this` to whatever you passed in. The difference between `#call` and `#apply` is how you supply further arguments to pass into the function. With `#call` you supply them as further arguments to the `#call` call (e.g. `func.call(thisArg, arg0, arg1, arg2)`), whereas with `#apply` you supply them as an array in the second argument (`func.apply(thisArg, [arg0, arg1, arg2])`).
2. Using dotted notation: If you have an object that has a property with a function assigned to it (like your `start` property), calling it by using the object instance, a dot, and the property name (`this.start()` or `foo.start()`, etc.) will call the function and set `this` to the object instance within the call. So the dotted notation does two *entirely distinct* things: Looks up the property and finds a function as its value, and calls the function such that `this` is set to the object during the call. Literally it's like: `var f = obj.func; f.call(obj)`.

Slightly off-topic, but: Barring a really good reason to, I wouldn't reinvent this wheel. There are lots of libraries out there to simply XHR calls. [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), and nearly all the rest.

Comment: mind-opening post. thank you so much. (and it works too, hehe.)

Comment: @Radu: Good deal, glad that helped. (I notice you're new here: If this answered your question, click the check mark to the left of the answer near the top. That marks your question as "answered" and credits this as the right answer.)

Comment: @Radu: Agree w/ T.J.  Lib like jQuery really makes this much simpler by removing a lot of plumbing code.  see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I have been pulling my hair for hours trying to figure this out. My code is now working. Life is good again.